# Juju on CloudStack

Tags: juju

(How) can I run Juju on top of CloudStack?
I read this might be possible using the EC2 driver by setting the ec2-uri but I'm not sure how to do this in the current version of Juju.

Answer (score 1):

I think we answered this on the Juju list, but I'm posting here in case anyone else is searching for this.

The short answer is that CloudStack is not an officially supported cloud for Juju, and specific provider code for it is not currently on the roadmap.

It is possible to get many of the benefits of native support by using Juju's manual provider, as [documented here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-manual).

Comment: Also, in case anyone would be interested in developing a CloudStack provider for Juju, some documentation for writing a provider for Juju can be found here: https://github.com/juju/juju/wiki/Implementing-environment-providers.